# Why is there "Watch later as <username>" instead of just "Watch later" on YouTube?

Tags: youtube, user-interface, youtube-watch-later

A picture is worth a thousand words. Here:

[image: watch later as... image]

My question is about the '*Watch later as...*' part. This icon could've just said '*Watch later*' but it specifically mentions the username. What this suggests to me is either:

1. The 'as...' part is a variable. i.e. I can watch later as some different user, a feature of YouTube unknown to me
   **OR**
2. (Unlikely) YouTube just kept it that way to make user verify the username he/she's using. (In case he/she accidentally adds it to someone else's watch later playlist(?) ).

Anyone know what's the case?

I know this is rather silly question but I see no reason developers in a company like YouTube just made it like that without a reason.

Answer (score 2):

You may be signed into multiple Google accounts. Google will use your "primary" Google account (typically the one you signed into first) as the account to use for liking, disliking, commenting and adding to "Watch Later" lists.